# canceling touchend event when touchmove starts

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, touch, web-applications

I have a scrollable list in my web app, using [scrollability](http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/) to deal with the `overflow:scroll` feature. although when I finish scrolling and take my finger out of the screen the event bellow also triggers.

```
$('li').live('touchend', function (e) {
    //...
});
```

The thing is that I only would like this event above to fire when the action there's no touchmove event before that.

it is possible to suppress a `touchend` event from inside the `touchmove` event?
so it simulates better the iOS UITableView component? where when `touchmove` starts it cancels the target for `touchend`

Comment: Perhaps set a flag in `touchmove` which can be tested in `touchend` and if the flag is set, just skip the functionality and possibly `preventDefault()` (either way, reset the flag at the end).

Comment: thanks a lot Yaniro, that was the smartest thing to do in this case. If you could set this as an anser I would be happy to mark this a correct :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set a flag in `touchmove` which can be tested in `touchend` and if the flag is set, just skip the functionality and possibly `preventDefault()` (either way, reset the flag at the end).