# ignoring a touchend event when preceded by a touchmove event

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, mobile

Using jquery, I have an event that fires on touchend.  I do not want that event to fire when the user scrolls (touchmove).  The only thing I've found on SO is this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648863/canceling-touchend-event-when-touchmove-starts), but I don't like it.  It feels hacky.  It hurts my head to think that there isn't away to figure this out without setting a global flag, simply to check if a touchmove has occurred.

Is there anyway to figure the order of events out?  Some wrapper that encapsulates all the touch events that occurred.  Because this is for work and the powers that be don't want to bloat our code base with libraries, I can't use an external library, but if anyone knows a library that has this functionality that i could peruse for inspiration that would also be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648863/canceling-touchend-event-when-touchmove-starts

Comment: @ClintWarner Thanks.  I ended up doing the same thing even though I am not a fan of using global flags like that

Comment: Yeah, me either, but sometimes you have to go way out of your way to avoid them